# Number Input form validation doesn't show the right error message

Tags: angular, angular-material2

The validation works but I always get the same error message linked with required when the input error is about min/max.

And another issue that the error message is only shown when i click outside the input first time.

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';

export class myClass implements OnInit {
    myform: FormGroup;

    constructor  (private _fb:FormBuilder){}

    public someAmount = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.min(10), Validators.max(300)]);

    ngOnInit():void {
        this.myform = this._fb.group({
            someAmount: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.min(10), Validators.max(300)]]
        });
    }
}
```

**component.html**

```
 <form novalidate [formGroup]="myform" class="col-sm-4 form-group">
     <md-input-container>
         <input mdInput id="amount"
                       name="someAmount"
                       formControlName="someAmount"
                       type="number"
                       class="form-control "
                       [(ngModel)]="amount"
                       placeholder="amount"
                       (keyup)="onAmountChange()"/>
         <md-error *ngIf="someAmount.hasError('required')">
             <span> number required </span>
         </md-error>
         <md-error *ngIf="someAmount.hasError('min')" class="top-margin-medium text-center bold alert-danger">
             <span>amount should be not less than 10 </span>
         </md-error>
         <md-error *ngIf="someAmount.hasError('max')" class="top-margin-medium text-center bold alert-danger">
             <span>amount should be not more than 300</span>
         </md-error>
     </md-input-container>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the validation messages to point to the formcontrol with the following `*ngIf`:

```
*ngIf="myform.hasError('required', 'someAmount')"
*ngIf="myform.hasError('min', 'someAmount')"
*ngIf="myform.hasError('max', 'someAmount')"
```

Furthermore...

While it's not explicitly stated in the docs that they `ngModel` and reactive forms should not be used together, we can gather from the fact that `ngModel` directive is not included in `ReactiveFormsModule`, that perhaps we shouldn't use them together :)

so I'd suggest you remove `ngModel` and only have the form control:

```
<input mdInput formControlName="someAmount"
               type="number"
               (keyup)="onAmountChange()"/>
```

Well, now you are missing the two-way-binding? No, we can handle the binding with just the form controls instead of needing `ngModel`. If you have an initial value, you can set it when you build the form:

```
someAmount: ['initial value', [....]]
```

or if you are receiving the value "later", you can use `setValue` (or `patchValue`):

```
this.myform.controls.someAmount.setValue("new value!")
```

if you need to access the value...

```
this.myform.get('someAmount').value
```

As for the validation error not showing unless you focus out from the input field, it seems it's still a bug? https://stackoverflow.com/a/39196394/7741865 which you can hack with using `md-hint` instead:

```
<md-hint *ngIf="myform.hasError('min', 'someAmount')" [ngStyle]="{'color': 'red'}"> 
   <span>amount should be not less than 10 </span> 
</md-hint>
```

DEMO: https://plnkr.co/edit/ncEjsTseFLkQsHLWU2Gr?p=preview

Comment: Thanks I added this attribute as well to <md-input-container color="{{ !myform.valid ? 'warn' : 'primary' }}"> so the workaround behaves exactly like md-error

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two main problems with the code above.

In your html you are referencing the variable 'useramount' which is nowhere defined in your component ( it is defined as someAmount ).

Futhermore, the formControl assigned to the someAmount variable is not linked to the form group, hence no errors/changes will be associated with it.

You need to adjust your component code as follows

```
 export class myClass implements OnInit {
     myform: FormGroup;
     useramount:AbstractControl;

     constructor  (private _fb:FormBuilder){}

     ngOnInit():void {
         this.myform = this._fb.group({
             someAmount: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.min(40), Validators.max(300)]]
         });
         this.useramount = this.myform.get('someAmount');
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It's my bad when writing the question here! in my code it's useramount instead of someAmount! i edited my code in the question so this issue is not the problem! but in this line this.someAmount = this.myform.get('someAmount'); method get doesn't seem to exist for FormGroup! it doesn't even build when i put this line!

Comment: Something's wrong in that case. The get method is defined in the AbstractControl class, https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl which is extended by the FormGroup class.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to JeanPaul who pointed out that the formControl is not linked to the formGroup.

I was able to get it to work by doing this in my html:

```
   <md-error *ngIf="myform.controls['someAmount'].hasError('required')>
          <span> required error message </span>
   </md-error>
   <md-error *ngIf="myform.controls['someAmount'].hasError('min')>
          <span>min error message</span>
   </md-error>
   <md-error *ngIf="myform.controls['someAmount'].hasError('max')>
          <span>max error message</span>
   </md-error>
```

Comment: For me, this does not show the messages until you focus out https://plnkr.co/edit/Wuz0E9VWjOTrU5FhNmnl?p=preview from the input field, but maybe that's what you want :) But also consider removing the two-way-binding. It is redundant ;) But it's up to you :)

Comment: @AJT_82 Thanks for your response! i see your point in the tow way binding! but i still don't get the messages till i focus out! what is the issue here?

Comment: Apparently it's a bug (?) which you can hack. I wrote an answer earlier which I deleted when I saw your answer, but I undeleted that now and added the hack. Hope you don't mind the answer :)